# If a fighter multiclasses into sorcerer, when they cast spells do they also replace material components with somatic?

Tags: multi-classing, sorcerer, pathfinder-2e

From [the Sorcerer class page](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=11),

> Because you're a sorcerer, you can usually replace material components with somatic components, so you don't need to use a material component pouch.

I interpret this to mean that whenever a sorcerer casts a spell that requires a material component (without a cost), then they can choose to replace that component with a somatic one. From [the listing on spell components](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=281), this means that the spell would keep the manipulate trait, but one important thing would change: the spell no longer requires you to have a hand free to retrieve and manipulate the material component.

Now, if a fighter takes the sorcerer dedication, then [from the dedication page](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=11),

> You cast spells like a sorcerer.

I interpet *this* to mean that the fighter also gains the ability to replace any material component with a somatic component, and that as a consequence the fighter can cast sorcerer spells without needing a hand free.

Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 2):

### No further guidance is given, but it seems most likely yes

**like** *preposition*

> having the same **characteristics or qualities** as; similar to.

The rules on [spellcasting archetypes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=170) offer no help for this question, so we are left with the rules you quote from [Sorcerer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=11) and their [archetype](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=11). Unfortunately, the phrase "cast spells like a sorcerer" is a bit ambiguous, but the result seems to be that you can use Cast a Spell action using the "characteristics [and/]or qualities" of the Sorcerer spellcasting feature*.

Because not needing a spell component pouch is *characteristic* to Sorcerer spellcasting, that a *quality* of the rules is "usually replac[ing] material components with somatic components", it would seem that you have this benefit.

This makes sense, as, in-world, you are *also* a sorcerer, not "kind of" a sorcerer. You have a bloodline (although maybe watered down, depending on how your character is written) and otherwise could be mistaken for a sorcerer if not for running around in heavy (if you want) armor swinging a greatsword (or other weapon of choice).

- Oddly, you are not *considered* to have the "spellcasting" class feature until you take Basic Sorcerer Spellcasting, per the rules on spellcaster archetypes. This does not affect that you are Casting a Spell "like" a sorcerer.